# Populate email with entries from modal form

Tags: html, html-email, mailto, subject

I have a modal form (see HTML snippet for the modal form - this is just a small part of the overall page HTML) to allow users to submit new links to me. This is a local HTML file that I maintain for my team on a shared drive, and we do not have access to serves to host this on, so when a new link is submitted, I just go in and update the HTML with the new link.

I would like to be able to grab the values from each field of the modal-body populate the body of an email, each on it's own line like this:

- Name: [value entered in Name field]
- URL: [value entered in URL field]
- Description: [value entered in Description field]
- Category: [value selected from NewCat dropdown field]

I'd also like the Subject line to populate with "New Link Submitted" or something like that.

```js
  var emailTO = "test@example.com"
  var emailSubj = "New Link Submission"
  var newName = document.getElementById("newName").value
  var newURL = document.getElementById("newURL").value
  var newDescrip = document.getElementById("newDescrip").value
  var newCat = document.getElementById("newCat").value
  var emailBody = newName % OA % OA newURL % OA % OA newDescrip % OA % OA newCat

function emailLink(){

/* ?????? */

}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal" align="center">
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">
      <span id="close" class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Submit New Link</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Name: <input type="text" class="newName" id="newName" value="newName" </p>
        <p>URL: <input type="text" class="newURL" id="newURL" value="newURL" </p>
          <p>Description: <input type="text" class="newDesrcip" id="newDesrcip" value="" </p>
            <form>
              <p>Category:
                <select id="newCat" required>
                  <option value="A"> A </option>
                  <option value="B"> B </option>
                  <option value="C"> C </option>
                  <option value="D"> D </option>
                </select>
              </p>
            </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="submit_link_button" value="Submit" onclick="emailLink()">

    <!--
I would like to be able to grab the values from each field of the modal-body populate the body of an email, each on it's own line like this:
Name: [value entered in Name field]
URL: [value entered in URL field]
Description: [value entered in Description field]
Category: [value selected from NewCat dropdown field]

I'd also like the Subject line to populate with "New Link Submitted" or something like that.
-->


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should use an `a` tag with `href` attribute contains your desired e-mail. But keep in mind, when you click that `a` tag you don't send the e-mail automatically you just prompt the default e-mailing software/application in your machine(i.e: Outlook on Windows, Gmail on Android...) then you have to press send to send that email to the e-mail that's provided in the `mailto` URL of the `a` tag. By adding the subject, message etc... you'll get these informations placed in their appropriate places when the default messaging application appears. Hope you get the point of using the `mailto` URL.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm fine with having to click send on the email  - I'm more stuck with how to populate the body of the email with the four pieces of information entered into the modal form (Name, URL, Description, and Category)

Comment: use `JavaScript` ! Did you done any attempt ?

Comment: I'm new to JS, but I've defined my variables (I updated the code snippet above)- just not sure where to go from there to have JS build the email. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Sure, I can do this. But, it's not that clear where to put the name, the URL, the description... I think they should be in the body of the email - Am I right ?

Comment: You got it - each on its won line if possible.

Comment: Alright, a moment, I'll post an answer.

Comment: check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have some mistakes in your `HTML` code(the `input` tags are not closed properly) that I managed to correct them.

You don't need a `form` tag to acheive your goal, you can use it but an `a` tag would suffice. So, instead of the `<input type="button" id="submit_link_button" value="Submit" onclick="emailLink()">` I changed it to `<a href="" id="contact-link">Send</a>` tag which has `href` attribute that accepts 'mailto' links, and that attribute will be filled by `JavaScript` by the desired informations, and I gave it an `id="contact-link"` to reference it by `JavaScript`.

> You used to use an 'inline event handler' in the `input` with `type="button"`(the one that will be replaced by an `a` tag) which is a bad practice. Instead, it's better to use the built-in `addEventListener` method to attach an event handler to whatever element you want. [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) about `addEventListener` method.

Here's a runnable snippet the illustrates all what being said.

```js
// select the 'a' tag that has the mailto link to reference later in the code.
var contactLink = document.getElementById('contact-link');
// add click event listener to that 'a' tag.
contactLink.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // get all the information required by getting the inputs and the select tags values.
  var newName = document.getElementById("newName").value,
      newURL = document.getElementById("newURL").value,
      newDescrip = document.getElementById("newDesrcip").value, 
      newCat = document.getElementById("newCat").value,
      /* the subject variable holds the subject of the email, change its value per your requirement. */
      subject = 'New Link Submitted',
      /* the queryString variable holds the email's subject and body to be used in the href attribute of the 'a' tag. the '\n' character is used to make a new line and it must be encoded, along with other special characters as the space, in a valid URL format, we'll be using the built-in 'encodeURI' method for that task. */
      queryString = '?subject=' + subject + '&body=Name: ' + newName + '\nURL: ' + newURL + '\nDescription: ' + newDescrip + '\nCategory: ' + newCat,
      /* the emailAddr variable holds the email which you want the email to be sent to. Change its value per your requirement. */
      emailAddr = 'test@exemple.com';
  /* assign the href attribute of the 'a' tag by the queryString variable's value prepended by the desired email adress, and encode all the resulted string in the URL format using the built-in 'encodeURI' method. */
  this.href = window.encodeURI('mailto:' + emailAddr + queryString);
  // just for testing to see the resulted href string. Delete this line in production phase.
  console.log(this.href);
});
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal" align="center">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
  <span id="close" class="close">&times;</span>
  <h3>Submit New Link</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Name: <input type="text" class="newName" id="newName" value="newName" / ></p>
  <p>URL: <input type="text" class="newURL" id="newURL" value="newURL" / ></p>
  <p>Description: <input type="text" class="newDesrcip" id="newDesrcip" value="" / ></p>
  <p>
    Category:
    <select id="newCat" required>
      <option value="A"> A </option>
      <option value="B"> B </option>
      <option value="C"> C </option>
      <option value="D"> D </option>
    </select>
  </p>
</div>
<br>
<!-- no Form tag is needed, and also the 'input' with 'type=button' is replaced by the next 'a' tag -->
<a href="" id="contact-link">Send</a>
```

> [Learn
>   more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)
>   about the `encodeURI` method.

**Ps:** in order to make all of this work, the user must configure his default mailing application, otherwise nothing will happen.

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: sorry for the delay in feedback, I've been out of the office unexpectedly. The above worked perfectly - and I've learned a few things along the way - thanks a lot!